# Can I target multiple Xcode/Swift versions with a single Cocoapod?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a Swift framework that I'm compiling and deploying via CocoaPods.

I've been using XCode 9.0 to develop in Swift 4.0, packaged that up in to a CocoaPod and that has all worked fine.

I then upgraded to XCode 10, only to find that when I include my CocoaPod it doesn't like the fact that the Pod was compiled in an older version of XCode.

From my understanding, this means that if I want to consume my Pod in an XCode 10 project, I would have to build the Pod in the same Xcode version.
So does this also mean that if I want my Pod to support as many versions as possible, I would need to do individual builds with specific Xcode versions and then release them to separate CocoaPod repos (or versions)?

Am I missing something basic that allows me to support as many Swift/Xcode versions as possible?

Cheers
Dave

Comment: Hey did you solve this issue. I am having the same problem

Comment: @USER9561 see my answer below. I ended up deploying the code in the Cocoapod and letting the end user compile it.

Comment: how did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I was shipping the compiled binary inside a Cocoapod as opposed to the source code. Unfortunately the compiled binaries from Swift are not forward nor backward compatible.

The pod is now deployed source only which unfortunately means people can see the shocking code that I have to stand over which I did not write! #legacyproblems

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3, 4, and 4.2 targets can coexist and link together.

> You decide when and if you’d like to migrate on a per-target basis
> when it makes sense for your project. While migrating to Swift 4.2 is
> definitely encouraged, it’s not an all-or-nothing process, as Swift 3,
> 4, and 4.2 targets can coexist and link together.

## Different cocoapod and different project version can also coexist.

You wish to have different cocoapod version as compared to your project version then you shoud make following changes at the end of your pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
    print "Setting the default SWIFT_VERSION to 4.2\n"
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if ['SomeTarget-iOS', 'SomeTarget-watchOS'].include? "#{target}"
            print "Setting #{target}'s SWIFT_VERSION to 3.0\n"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
            end
        else
            print "Setting #{target}'s SWIFT_VERSION to Undefined (Xcode will automatically resolve)\n"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings.delete('SWIFT_VERSION')
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Sometimes even after you run pod update your xcode forcefully update your cocoapod's project version, then in that case select cocoapod pod project and change the swift version in the build settings.